# Python - Difficulty Calculating Partition Function using Large NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I had a pretty compact way of computing the partition function of an Ising-like model using itertools, lambda functions, and large NumPy arrays. Given a network consisting of `N` nodes and `Q` "states"/node, I have two arrays, `h`-fields and `J`-couplings, of sizes `(N,Q)` and `(N,N,Q,Q)` respectively. J is upper-triangular, however. Using these arrays, I have been computing the partition function `Z` using the following method:

```
# Set up lambda functions and iteration tuples of the form (A_1, A_2, ..., A_n)
iters = itertools.product(range(Q),repeat=N)
hf = lambda s: h[range(N),s]
jf = lambda s: np.array([J[fi,fj,s[fi],s[fj]] \
                            for fi,fj in itertools.combinations(range(N),2)]).flatten()

# Initialize and populate partition function array
pf = np.zeros(tuple([Q for i in range(N)]))
for it in iters:
    hterms = np.exp(hf(it)).prod()
    jterms = np.exp(-jf(it)).prod()
    pf[it] = jterms * hterms

# Calculates partition function
Z = pf.sum()
```

This method works quickly for small `N` and `Q`, say `(N,Q) = (5,2)`. However, for larger systems `(N,Q) = (18,3)`, this method cannot even create the `pf` array due to memory issues because it has `Q^N` nontrivial elements. Any ideas on how to either overcome this memory issue or how to alter the code to work on subarrays?

Edit: Made a small mistake in the definition of `jf`. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the large array just by initializing Z to 0, and incrementing it by `jterms * iterms` in each iteration. This still won't get you out of calculating and summing Q^N numbers, however. To do that, you probably need to figure out a way to simplify the partition function algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to compute but I tested your code with ChrisB suggestion and jf will not work for Q=3.

Comment: Good catch. Most of the testing I did on the code was for Q=2 type systems. I have corrected the code above (by replacing `Q` in the `itertools.combinations` with 2).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you shouldn't use a dense numpy array to encode your function?  You could try sparse arrays or just straight Python with Numba compilation.  [This blogpost](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/02/28/Ising/) shows using Numba on the simple Ising model with good performance.